Testing MUI components that change with screen size
I have an MUI Drawer component that is given different props based on the size of the window -- above a certain window width, it becomes a permanent drawer and docks to the left side of the screen, and below a certain width it becomes a temporary drawer that is hidden until a button is pressed to reveal it.  Here is the full code for this component:
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Box, Divider, Drawer, List, Toolbar } from '@mui/material';
import ArchiveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Archive';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

import AppDataContext from '../../SupportingModules/AppDataContext';
import FilterCheckbox from './FilterCheckbox';
import TagEditor from './TagEditor';
import FeatureButton from './FeatureButton';
import DrawerHeader from './DrawerHeader';


/**
 * TagDrawer contains checkboxes to select tags for image filtering.
 * 
 * @returns The TagDrawer component to be rendered in the app.
 */
export default function TagDrawer() {
    const {appData, appState} = useContext(AppDataContext);
    const [editTags, setEditTags] = useState(false);
    const theme = useTheme();
    const smallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

    const drawerStyles = (style) => {
        const widthChooser = style=='permanent' ? 240 : "100%"
        return {
            backgroundColor: '#666666',
            width: widthChooser,
            flexShrink: 0,
            ['& .MuiDrawer-paper']:
                { width: widthChooser, backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa' },
            marginRight: '0.5%',
        };
    };

    const handleArchive = () => {
        // Not yet implemented
        console.log("Archive button clicked!");
    };

    const handleTrash = () => {
        // Not yet implemented
        console.log("Trash button clicked!");
    };

    const handleEdit = () => {
        // Toggle edit mode
        setEditTags(!editTags);
    };


    const permanentDrawerProps = {
        variant: 'permanent',
        sx: [drawerStyles('permanent'), {display: { xs: 'none', md: 'block' }}],
        'data-testid': 'permanent-drawer'
    };

    const temporaryDrawerProps = {
        variant: 'temporary',
        open: appState.drawerOpen,
        ModalProps: {keepMounted: true}, // improves performance
        sx: [drawerStyles('temporary'), {display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' }}],
        'data-testid': 'temporary-drawer'
    };
    
    return (
        <Drawer {...(smallScreen ? temporaryDrawerProps : permanentDrawerProps)}>
            <Toolbar/>
            <Box sx={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>
                <DrawerHeader handleEdit={handleEdit}/>
                <List> {/* List tags available for filtering */}
                        {(appData.tagData.map((tag) => {
                            const tagId = tag.id;
                            const tagName = tag.name;
                            return(
                                editTags ?
                                
                                <TagEditor
                                text={tagName}
                                key={tagId}
                                tagId={tagId}/>
                                :
                                <FilterCheckbox
                                text={tagName}
                                key={tagId}
                                tagId={tagId}/>
                            )
                        }))}
                </List>
                <Divider/>
                <List> {/* Misc non-tag/filter options */}
                    <FeatureButton
                        name="Archive"
                        startIcon={<ArchiveIcon/>}
                        action={handleArchive}
                        active={false}/>
                    <FeatureButton
                        name="Trash"
                        startIcon={<DeleteIcon/>}
                        action={handleTrash}
                        active={false}/>
                </List>
            </Box>
        </Drawer>
    );
};

I'm trying to test this component, including that it responds appropriately to changes in window size.  This has proven to be a little complicated, as changing the screen size hasn't been very straightforward, and jsdom doesn't support certain aspects of the window, and MUI's documentation is absolutely abysmal in all things, testing in particular.  Here's what I'm working with so far:
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import AppDataContext from '../../SupportingModules/AppDataContext';
import TagDrawer from './TagDrawer';

describe('TagDrawer', () => {
    let appData;
    let appState;
    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
        appData = {
            imageData: [], // not used in this component
            tagData: [
                {'id': '10', 'name': 'Favorites', 'owner': '1'},
                {'id': '12', 'name': 'Star Wars', 'owner': '1'},
                {'id': '13', 'name': 'Dad Jokes', 'owner': '1'}
            ],
            imageTagData: [] // not used in this component
        };
        appState = { drawerOpen: false };

        component = render(
            <AppDataContext.Provider value={{appData, appState}}>
                <TagDrawer/>
            </AppDataContext.Provider>
        )
    });
    
    test('shows permanent drawer on large screen', () => {
        // I know how to do this one but only because it renders large by default
    });

    test('shows temporary drawer on small screen', () => {
        Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            value: 150,
        });

        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

        expect(screen.getByTestId('temporary-drawer')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
    
    test('temporary drawer opens and closes', () => {
        // gotta figure out the above test first
    });

    test('correctly renders FilterCheckbox components', () => {
        const checkboxes = screen.getAllByRole('checkbox');
        expect(checkboxes.length).toEqual(appData.tagData.length);
    });

    test('correctly renders TagEditor components', () => {
        const editButton = screen.getByRole('switch');
        fireEvent(
            editButton,
            new MouseEvent('click', {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true
            })
        );

        const editors = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
        expect(editors.length).toEqual(appData.tagData.length);
    });
});

Currently the only failing test is the one where I am checking that testId 'temporary-drawer' is in the document.
I have read MUI's documentation on testing generally and on testing components using the useMediaQuery hook, but the two combined amount to less than four paragraphs and a useless, unexplained example, and have not been helpful to me in understanding what I need to do here (if you'd like details on what's confusing I'll provide in comments).  I understand that jsdom doesn't implement the window.matchMedia that is required for this hook to work, and that somehow the css-mediaquery package is supposed to help with this, but I can't find a full explanation anywhere, and in fact reading other sources just makes the issue more confusing, as everyone seems to have a totally different way to handle this every time I find a new source.
How can I get my component to render in a way that I can test it properly?
